# Can't import new definition although old definitions from same file are working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

Hello I have the file with path *project/top_file.py*

I have another file with path *project/subfolder/model.py*

In *topfile.py* At the moment I have the following code

```
from subfolder.model import definition_one, definition two
```

I can use now these two definitions in my topfile.

Now I added a new definition in model.py and called it definition_three
model.py looks this way now

```
def definition_one(...):
  ...
def defintion_two(...):
  ...
def definition_three(...):
  ...
```

I wanted to change the code in topfile.py to

```
from subfolder.model import definition_one, definition_two, definition_three
```

but I get the Error `Import Error: cannot import name 'definition_three'`

Comment: Maybe a typo in your code?

Comment: Are you running/testing this in the interpreter, or running a script directly?

Comment: It's not a typo.